# AlgoliaException in Client.php line 992: Index product_data does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, algolia

I just added laravel scout and configured everything as per documentation but when I just tested the query `return \App\ProductData::search('')->get();` it returns me following error

```
AlgoliaException in Client.php line 992:
Index product_data does not exist
```

and I have no clue why this error is being generated. Moreover, I am not seeing any indexes or records in my algolia dashboard. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Did you reindex your data first? The reindex create the index and then you'll be able to search on top of it.

Comment: @JanPetr how to reindex?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout#indexing

Comment: I have already indexed the data using `php artisan scout:import "App\ProductData"` @JanPetr

Answer (score 0):

Have you [correctly followed the instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scout)? You need to add a few things to your models in order to use Scout.

According to your error, *algolia* cannot find the model index. In ProductData, override the method from the Searchable trait:

```
public function searchableAs()
{
    return 'product_data_index';
}
```

Comment: but the table name is product_data

Answer (score 0):

For those people who have this problem. 
If you follow instruction on Laravel official hompage then successfully imported index and facing this error. Don't worry just because you've just imported index and Algolia hasn't finish it work. Wait for a while. If still can't, flush your index, restart your Laravel app and import Scout index again.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

As Jan Petr suggests, it seems like you forgot to reindex your data first.

```
php artisan scout:import "App\ProductData"
```

After that you should see your data in Algolia's dashboard.

Comment: I have the opposite, but it might be because of my configuration.